# Protecting routes with LDAP

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, active-directory, laravel-5.1

I am slightly confused by something.  For Authentication, I am using LDAP, more specifically this https://github.com/SaschaDens/ldap-connector

That LDAP library I am using essentially works on top of Laravels Authentication Facade.

Everything is fine, I can log in and out now using LDAP.  When logged in however, I have an update users buttons.  This essentially uses LDAP to get
all the groups a user is apart off.  So I have three tables,

```
users
groups
users_groups
```

When the button is pushed, I add all users to the users table.  I then add all unique groups to the groups table.  The last table users_groups is essentially a pivot table which links a users_id to a groups_id.

By the end of this, I can see that I am for instance apart of 3 groups, one of which is the admin group.  I can also see all members of this group by doing this

```
$group = Group::where('groupName', 'admin')->first();
$users = $group->user;
```

Now there are some routes I only want to make available to admin users.  I can see in Kernel.php there is the following

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
];
```

At the moment I am only using auth to make sure the user is logged in.  Obviously I do not have an admin one set up yet, and I think the way I am doing it there could be a problem because I am creating my own groups table.

How would I go about blocking access to a particular route to only users who are apart of the admin group?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a new route middleware.

1) create middleware class

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware
```

2) Add authentication logic to you AdminMiddleware class

```
if(Auth::user()->inGroup('GROUPNAME')) 
{
    return $next($request);
}
else
{
    return view('auth.login')->withErrors('You are not logged in');
}
```

3) Add the new middleware to your $routeMiddleware

```
'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware',
```

4) Add the middleware alias to the routes you wish to protect

```
Route::get('admin', [
    'as' => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'admin',
    'uses' => 'AdminController@getAdminPage'
]);
```